# "Upload image" alignment issue

Tags: bug, status-completed

There appears to be an issue with alignment on the "Upload Image" popup in both Internet Explorer and Google Chrome, as follows:

[image]

Upon clicking "From The Web", the alignment fixes itself, toggling back breaks it again. Only appears to be happening on Movies & TV.

Comment: It does this in Firefox, too. Just... so you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSS for this site includes a rule that reads:

```
#header br { display: none }
```

Since the image upload dialog is technically nested inside the `#header` div, this rule breaks all line breaks within the upload dialog (and in any other similar dialogs).

The `<br>` tag that the rule appears to be *meant to* suppress has a specific class name, so a simple fix would be to replace that rule with:

```
#header br.cbt { display: none }
```

Or, alternatively, we could just patch it with an extra rule like:

```
#header .popup br { display: inline }
```

Comment: Great call, that's exactly the problem. I just pushed a fix. Should be good to go on our next production server build.

Comment: Thanks, Kurtis. (Ps. Just on a random tangent, I used to assume that all SE employees had diamonds on all sites, just by virtue of working at SE. Has that changed, or has it always been just for certain employees? Just curious...)